# unable to parse - in Regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a bit new to the regular expressions in Javascript.

I am trying to write a function called `parseRegExpression()`
which parses the attributes passed and generates a key/value pairs
It works fine with the input:

```
"iconType:plus;iconPosition:bottom;"
```

But it is  not able to parse the input:

```
"type:'date';locale:'en-US';"
```

Basically the `-` sign is being ignored.  The code is at:

http://jsfiddle.net/visibleinvisibly/ZSS5G/

The Regular Expression key value pair is as below

```
/[a-z|A-Z|-]*\s*:\s*[a-z|A-Z|'|"|:|-|_|\/|\.|0-9]*\s*;|[a-z|A-Z|-]*\s*:\s*[a-z|A-Z|'|"|:|-|_|\/|\.|0-9]*\s*$/gi;
```

Comment: You don't need the `|` character inside of `[ ]` to act as "or"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems:

- A `|` inside a character class means a literal `|` character, not an alternation.
- A `.` inside a character class means a literal `.` character, so there's no need to escape it.
- A `-` as the first or last character inside a character class means a literal `-` character, otherwise it means a character range.
- There's no need to use `[a-zA-Z]` when you use the case-insensitive modifier (`i`); `[a-z]` is enough.
- The only difference between your alterations is the last bit; this can be simplified significantly by just limiting your alternation to that part which is different.

This should be equivalent to your original pattern:

```
/[a-z-]*\s*:\s*[a-z0-9'":_\/.-]*\s*(?:;|$)/gi
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace regular expressions in your code as follow:

```
regExpKeyValuePair = /[-a-z]*\s*:\s*[-a-z'":_\/.0-9]*\s*;|[-a-z]*\s*:\s*[-a-z'":-_\/.0-9]*\s*$/gi;              
regExpKey = /[-a-z]*/gi;
regExpValue = /[-a-z:_\/.0-9]*/gi;
```

- You don't need escape . inside `[]`.
- No need to put `|` between elements `[]`.
- Because you are using `/i` flag, [A-Z] is not needed.
- `-` should be at the beginning or at the end.

Comment: Try, pray and hope? Is this programming for you?

Comment: @6502, I tried it myself. I am sorry. I'm not good at English. Is `try` not an appropriate word?

Comment: Sorry, probably I overreacted. But programming is (or should be) like mathematics at least when talking about correctness. The word "try" ("and see what happens") suggests programming is unpredictable, and learning programming that way indeed makes your code unpredictable. There are places where trying and see is the only practical solution (e.g. performance, especially in the fine-tuning area), but this is not one of those cases.

Comment: @6502, You explanation sounds reasonable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the regex:

```
var test1 = "iconType:plus;iconPosition:bottom;";
var test2 = "type:'date';locale:'en-US';";

function toto(str) {
    var result = new Array();
    var temp = str.split(';');
    for (i=0; i<temp.length-1; i++) {
        result[i] = temp[i].split(':',1);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(toto(test1));
console.log(toto(test2));
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the key or the value need to be able to contain `:`.

Comment: I don't believe that the key can contain a `:`, but for the value, I have used the limit parameter of the split function.

Comment: With this simplified approach the value cannot contain `;`

Answer (score 0):

Inside a character set atom `[...]` the pipe char `|` is just a regular char and doesn't mean "or".

A character set atom lists characters or ranges you want to accept (or exclude if the character set starts with `^`) and "or" is implicit.

You can use a backslash in a character set if you need to include/exclude a close bracket `]`, the `^` sign, the dash `-` that is used for ranges, the backslash `\` itself, an unprintable character or if you want to use a non-ASCII unicode char specifying the code instead of literally.

Regular expression syntax however also lets you to avoid backslash-escaping in a character set atom by placing the character in a position where it cannot have the special meaning... for example a dash `-` as first or last in the set (it cannot mean a range there).

Note also that if you need to be able to match as values quoted strings, including backslash escaping, the regular expression is more complex, for example

```
'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'|"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"
```

matches a single-quoted or double-quoted string including backslash escaping, the meaning being:

- A single quote `'`
- Zero or more of either:

  - Any char except the single quote `'` or the backslash `\`
  - A pair composed of a backslash `\` followed by any char
- A single quote `'`

or the same with double quotes `"` instead.

Note that the groups have been delimited with `(?:...)` instead of plain `(...)` to avoid capture

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't match hyphens because it interpreting `|-|` as a range that starts at `|` and ends at `|`.  (I would have expected that to be treated as a syntax error, but there you have it.  It works the same in every regex flavor I've tried, too.)

Have a look at this regex:

```
/(?:^|;)([a-z-]*)\s*:\s*([a-z'":_\/.0-9-]*)\s*(?=;|$)/ig
```

As suggested by the other responders, I collapsed it to one alternative, removed the unneeded pipes, and escaped the hyphen by moving it to the end.  I also anchored it at the beginning as well as the end.  Or anchored it as well as I can, anyway.  I used a lookahead to match the trailing semicolon so it will still be there when the next match starts.  It's far from foolproof, but it should work okay as long as the input is well formed.